# Why can't my factory definition use another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am using the Rolify gem in a Rails 4.2 application.

I am using seed data in the factory which works. However, from what I have read, that's not the correct way to do it.

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to do so correctly without having to use complex factory calls in my spec files.

Here is my Employee factory:

```
require 'faker'

#Seed the database before running the tests only if in test mode
#Fixes problem with rake routes running this command and deleting out the database
Rails.application.load_seed if  Rails.env.test?

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :employee do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name}
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name}
    sequence(:email) { |n| "peterjohnson#{n}@example.com" }
    mobile 66816927867
    bio "MyText"
    address { Faker::Address.street_address}
    province_state { Faker::Address.state}
    country { Faker::Address.country}
    postal_code { Faker::Address.postcode}
    status :active
    bachelor_degree "B.Sc"
    password Faker::Internet.password(8)
    sequence(:paypal_email) { |n| "paypal_peterJohnson#{n}@example.com" }
    sequence(:skype_id) {|n| "peterjohnson_skype#{n}" }
    os :mac
    role_ids [Role.first.id]

    trait :proofreader do
        after(:create) {|employee| employee.add_role(:proofreader)}
    end

    trait :admin do
        after(:create) {|employee| employee.add_role(:admin)}
    end

    trait :super_admin do
        after(:create) {|employee| employee.add_role(:super_admin)}
    end
  end
end
```

I need to have the roles created before the Employee so that I can save their IDs in the Employee model.

In my application Roles are added via a form when an employee is registered.  So I can't do an after create to add the role for some of the tests.

If I create the roles within the Employee factory as follows:

```
factory :employee do
  ["proofreader", "admin", "super_admin"].each do |role|
      FactoryGirl.create(:role, name: role)
  end
  first_name { Faker::Name.first_name}
  ...
```

I get an error telling me that it can't find the factory named role. It exists as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :role do
    name :proofreader
  end
end
```

Here is my Employee model which validates that an Employee must have a role:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  # returns the full name of the employee. This code is found in a concern called name.rb
  include Name

  rolify

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable


  enum status: [:active, :vacation, :unemployed]

    enum os: [:mac, :windows]

    validates :first_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

  validates :last_name, 
            presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2}

    validates :email, email: true, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :paypal_email, email: true, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :skype_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :mobile, presence: true, numericality: true, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :address, :province_state, :country, :postal_code, :bachelor_degree, :os,:status, :role_ids,  presence: true 



end
```

So how can I create the Employee with a role without seeding the database?

Comment: `rake routes` shouldn't touch your factories.  Are you sure you didn't mean something like `rake db:reset` or `rake db:seed`?

Comment: I agree it shouldn't but it does. That's the strange thing is that the it runs the seeds.rb file for no apparent reason except that Rails.application.load_seed exists in the Employees.rb factory which is even stranger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to `FactoryGirl.create(:role)` when factory_girl reads the `:employee` factory definition. The `:employee` factory is in `employee.rb` and the `:role` factory is in `role.rb` (or something like that), and factory_girl probably reads factory definitions in alphabetical order by file name, so when `:employee` is defined `:role` doesn't exist yet.

You need to create all roles when the test runs, after all factories have been defined.

In the `:employee` factory, change how you initialize `role_ids`:

```
role_ids { [(Role.first || FactoryGirl.create(:role, name: :default)).id] }
```

(Actually you should just be able to set `roles` instead of `role_ids` so you don't have to call `.id` on the default role.)

Then add the additional role in a callback in a trait:

```
trait :proofreader do
  after(:create) do |employee|
    FactoryGirl.create :role, name: :proofreader
    employee.add_role(:proofreader)
  end
end
```

However, assuming your roles don't change except when your application code also changes, I'd use seeds. It would be a lot simpler, and I don't know why it would be incorrect. I've done it with seeds on several projects and it works well.

Comment: Thanks Dave for the code and the explanation.  I should be more clear about why I can't do this for some tests. The reason is that I have feature tests that have a form where it displays the roles as checkboxes.  I need those roles to be populated so that I can have the checkboxes present.  I have validation that checks that a Employee must have a role assigned before it can save. So I can't create an Employee that does not have a role assigned.  If you know a way to do that correctly or if what I'm doing is ok then great. I'm a NOOB and a trying to do things best practices.

Comment: I thought that might be it. I guess the traits that you show above wouldn't work, then, since you couldn't create the employee in the first place. Does it work if you create and add a role in `after(:build)` instead of `after(:create)`? You might need to bypass `add_role` and add the role to the employee yourself.

Comment: The traits work because I seed the database first, otherwise you are correct they don't work.  I will try out the after and report back if that is the way to go.

Comment: My validation that requires role_ids to be present. So I can't build an employee object

Comment: Do you mean that `Employee` has a validation which requires an employee to have a role? If so, how could the traits ever work even with seeds? Better add your validation to your question.

Comment: The traits work because I seed the database with those roles. When I create an Employee in the Factory I give them the default role is for the first Role in the database.  Then I add to these roles using the traits.

Comment: I see: it's the default role that's being created too early. I revised my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dave. You provide and excellent solution.  I may still use seeds as you say my roles don't change. However, I like the clarity of what you provide.  I would not have to use role_ids in the Factory except that I need to validate that a role has been given to an Employee from the form.  We can't set a default role as we don't know what kind of employee we are hiring.  With rolify and Devise I have to send in role_ids[].  My way of validating it is to make sore that the role_ids exist. There may be a better way to validate it though. I'm still learning.

Comment: Thanks Dave. You provide and excellent solution.  I may still use seeds as you say my roles don't change. However, I like the clarity of what you provide.  I would not have to use role_ids in the Factory except that I need to validate that a role has been given to an Employee from the form.  We can't set a default role as we don't know what kind of employee we are hiring.  With rolify and Devise I have to send in role_ids[].  My way of validating it is to make sore that the role_ids exist. There may be a better way to validate it though. I'm still learning.